# How to calculate weekends of time range using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate weekends of time range using MySQL.

This is what I have so far(about calculate working days but i want to calculate weekends):

```
select
    (floor(days / 7)* 5
    + days%7
    - case
        when 6 between wd and wd + days%7 - 1 then 1
        else 0
    end
    - case
        when 7 between wd and wd + days%7 - 1 then 1
        else 0
    end) as result
from
    (
    select
        abs(datediff('2022-05-15', '2022-05-13')) + 1 as days,
        weekday('2022-05-13') + 1 as wd ) as a;
```

Hope I explained well...

Thanks.

Comment: What problems do you have?  Does the code work as you would expect?

Comment: Hi.I want to calculate weekends of time range using MySQL.

Comment: That is the requirement - what are the problems you are having in getting it to work?

Comment: i posted the code that works,but not my except,because does not counting weekends

Comment: how do you define a weekend, something like a saturday sunday or dates which are multiples of 6 and 7 in your range?

Comment: ohhh. i mean saturday or sunday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
(floor(days / 7)* 2
+ case
    when 6 between wd and wd + days%7 - 1 then 1
    else 0
end
+ case
    when 7 between wd and wd + days%7 - 1 then 1
    else 0
end) as result
```

from (  select
abs(datediff('2022-05-15', '2022-05-13')) + 1 as days,
weekday('2022-05-13') + 1 as wd ) as a;

Maybe this will work. Have a try.

Comment: You have to explain what you changed and why think that those changes will produce the correct result. Just posting code without any explanation is not helpfull.